# Why does Angular Router receive query params twice?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-router

I have an app which has two pages with lists.
On list page A I can click on an item and it will display the detail page of the item. On this detail page I have a list with sub-items and if I click on one of these sub-items I will be navigated to list page B with a query param of the ID of the sub-item. List page B is the summary of all sub-items of the items of page A.
I can also navigate from list page B to the detail page of list-page A with a router Param of the item and a query param of the sub item.

!!! I need the query params for filtering the items !!!

So my problem is when I navigate from list page B to the detail page with item ID and the sub-item ID as query param all is working fine. But if I then navigate to list Page A and navigate to an item detail the subscription of query param first recieves **no** query param because on page A will no query param be set and then the subscription recieves the **old** query param from the old navigation from list page B.

How can I solve this problem?

PS: I know I can code a workaround with a flag but that's not a nice solution.

**Edit:**
Link from list page B to detail page:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/detail-page', item.id]" [queryParams]="{sub_item: sub_item.id}" queryParamsHandling="merge">{{item.id}}</a>
```

Link from list page A to detail page:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/detail-page', item.id]">{{item.id}}</a>
```

Link from detail page to list page B:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/page-b']" [queryParams]="{sub_item: sub_item.id}">{{sub_item.id}}</a>
```

QueryParams-Subscription on detail page(this subscription is recieving query params twice):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe((data) => {
    this.subItemId = data.sub_item ? data.sub_item: "";
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe it could help to share some code?

Comment: I have added my router links and the query params subscription

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour might happen if you forgot to unsubscribe the query params subscription. Try unsubscribing the subscription on ngOnDestory.

In Component.ts:

```
routeSubscription: any;
ngOnInit() {
  this.routeSubscription = this.route.queryParams.subscribe((data) => {
    this.subItemId = data.sub_item ? data.sub_item: "";
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: thx for your response but I have already tried it and didn't solve my problem